# How can I convert an unstructured string to a dataframe?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a long string text that I would like to convert to a dataframe to analyze. Please see below for a sample of the data below. I would like the columns to be "Facility", "Street", "City", "Phone", and "Store Hours".

```
string = AlaskaUSCG Base Ketchikan 1300 Stedman Street  Ketchikan, AK  (907) 228-0250 Mon-Fri 7:30am-5pm | Sat 10am-4pm | Closed Sunday USCG Base Kodiak Albatros Avenue, Building 26 (2nd Floor)  Kodiak, AK  (907) 487-5773 USCG Base Kodiak Albatros Avenue, Building 26 (1st Floor)  Kodiak, AK  (907) 487-5773 Mon-Fri: 7am-9pm | Sat: 9am-9pm |
```

I have used StringIO to convert it to a dataframe but it converts it into a dataframe with 0 rows and 1000 columns. Instead I would like the columns I mentioned above and rows for each store.

I expect it to look like this with the data populated as rows:

```
Facility                    Street               City           Phone   
Alaska USCG Base Ketchikan  1300 Stedman Street  Ketchikan, AK  (907) 228 0250
```

Comment: There you go, the website is waaay a better source for your needs than that raw string. Take a read about `BeautifulSou`p and how to parse XML files (in this case, HTML). You want to extract values between the `p` tags (i.e. <p>value</p>) and clean those values. Use some library to get the .HTML file first (like `urllib` or `requests` libraries) and try to read some basic examples on how to parse the response from those libraries with `bs4`.

Comment: @rafaelc Thanks for your help. I actually originally tried to use ```BeautifulSoup``` to scrape the information, but I was having issues getting it to work properly so I pivoted into trying some string manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use simple web-scraping techniques, such as `bs4` and `requests`.

```
import bs4 

r = requests.get(URL)
b = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```

```
addresses = []

for val in b.find_all(name='p'):
  s = list(val.stripped_strings)
  if s and not s[0].startswith('HOURS'): addresses.append(' '.join(s[:-1]))
```